# Probability that no partial sum of a permutation of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ are divisible by $3$

Tags: probability, number-theory, permutations, combinations, divisibility

> Assume that $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n$ is a completely random permutations of numbers $1$ to $n$. What is the probability that none of the $n$ partial sums $A_1 = a_1$, $A_2 = a_1 + a_2, \dots$, and $A_n = a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n$ are divisible by three?

Here are my attempts: Since $1+\dots+n = n(n+1)/2$, we have that $n = 1 \mod 3$. Let $n = 3k + 1$ and let $N(i)$ be the number of numbers in $\{1,\dots,n\}$ that are $i\mod 3$, then

$$N(1) = N(2) + 1 = N(0) + 1 = k+1.$$

Here is one way I found to avoid divisibility by three:

1. Permutations of $1,1,2,1,2, \cdots$ ($0$s can be calculated separately)

---

I would appreciate it if someone could help me to move forward and finish my solution.

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: How many permutations are there, esp if you ignore the 0's? In particular, for $n \equiv 2, 0 \pmod{3}$, do any permutations exist? Have you found the only possibility?

Comment: I think this should not be closed as duplicate because the current question asks for the probability (not the number of permutations) and for general $n$ (not a specific $n$). Indeed the current question admits a more elegant solution compared to the accepted answer of the "duplicate".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you are correct that the probability is $0$ unless $n \equiv 1 \mod 3$. So let $n=3k+1$.

Consider modulo $3$. The permutation cannot start with a $0$, so the admissible fraction is $\frac{2k+1}{3k+1}$.

Given that there is one more $1$ than $2$s and $0$s, you found the only way (ignoring $0$s for now) of success:
$$1,1,2,1,2,\dots, 1, 2.$$

Let $X$ be a multiset of $k+1$ copies of $1$ and $k$ copies of $2$. Then, there are $\binom{2k+1}{k}$ ways to arrange set $X$, but only one way is successful, so the probability is

$$\frac{2k+1}{3k+1}\binom{2k+1}{k}^{-1}.$$